# Different links in Mockito

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy, mockito, spock

I need to test method like this:

```
...
        QueryBuilder builder = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("text", request.getText());
        Query query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(builder).build();

        SearchHits<ElasticData> hits = elasticsearchRestTemplate.search(query, ElasticData.class, IndexCoordinates.of(request.getIndex()));
...
```

So, what I do:

```
    def "service should return data from elastic correctly"() {
        setup:
            def request = new FindRequest("please", "blue", 1L, 1L)
-> problem here ->  def query = new NativeSearchQueryBuilder().withQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("text", request.getText())).build()
            def template = Mockito.mock(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.class)
            def service = new FileServiceImpl(new TikaParser(), template, new RestTemplate())
            def hits = new ArrayList()
            hits.add(new SearchHit("first", 1.0f, null, null, new ElasticData("F", "S", "blue")))
            hits.add(new SearchHit("second", 0.91f, null, null, new ElasticData("S", "T", "blua")))
            def items = new SearchHitsImpl(1L, null, 1.0f, null, hits, null)
            Mockito.when(template.search(query, ElasticData.class, IndexCoordinates.of(request.index))).thenReturn(items)

            def result = new ArrayList()
        when:
            service.getData(request)
        then:
            result.contains(new FoundItem("first", new ElasticData("F", "S", "blue")))
            result.contains(new FoundItem("second", new ElasticData("S", "T", "blua")))
    }
```

Of course I create new instance of NativeSearchQueryBuilder, and that`s the problem. But how do I do this different?

Thank you.

Comment: Can't you inject the builder in the constructor?

Comment: How should any items end up in the `result` array, it is never passed anywhere? Also I don't really understand what you want to test here. There is also no need to mock `query` as it is passed to your other mock, so you should either use an `ArgumentCaptor` or a simple `isA`/`any` for the parameter.